# Force to English Qwerty in C# TextBox

Tags: c#

I bought a Code bar Scanner to use it in my C# app in our local store

The Problem is the codebar scanner convert numbers to symbols
ex:

```
'18092630' => '&_àçé-"à'
'3CE824093DB4' => '"CE_é'àç"DB''
```

until I Changed the keyboard layout from Azerty to Qerty

*the question is how to force TextBox to use Qerty layout without Changing the Input language or adding a qerty layout  *

> I need to keep my local language (fr-FR) as it is!

Comment: possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37291533/change-keyboard-layout-from-c-sharp-code-with-net-4-5-2

Comment: So do you have problem with the scanner or with the TextBox? What symbols are coming from the scanner itself (you can see it in debugger)?

Comment: I had deal with scanners over 10 years ago, but I remember some scanners can be set up via scanning spesial service code, and the one of settings to adjust was used charset. Check the manual to your model, maybe, you can solve the problem in this manner.

Comment: The Problem with the scanner coz when  I changed the layout from English azerty to English Qerty it works!
e.g: '&' is '1' if you not clicked shift; by default & is 1 in Qerty Layout.

Comment: the really Problem I have is here:
https://superuser.com/questions/990248/barcode-scanner-works-only-with-english-layout