# powershell sendkeys doesn't work properly with arabic character

Tags: powershell

i have a problem with using sendkeys powershell method, so when i type this code in the console:

```
$obj = New-Object -com Wscript.Shell

$obj.SendKeys("a")
```

with keyboard configured in french language, i have the character `a` displayed, but when i turn the language of the keyboard to Arabic (Algeria), i get the character `ش` displayed instead of `ض`, it looks like the keyboard change from azerty configuration to qwerty.
also, i've tried to change arabic configuration of the keyboard to arabic (102) AZERTY, arabic (102) and arabic (101)
can someone help me please.

Comment: This might solve your issue: `$enc = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8` > `$char=$enc.GetString($enc.GetBytes('ش'))` > `$obj.SendKeys($char)`. Someone had a similar issue in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66701631/powershell-unicode-characters-transforming-unexpectedly/66701778#66701778

Comment: The [`SendKeys` method](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5169.vbscript-sendkeys-method.aspx) is used to send keystrokes to the currently active window **as if they where typed from the keyboard**. So `SendKeys` uses [Keyboard Scan Codes](https://www.millisecond.com/support/docs/v6/html/language/scancodes.htm) rather than (unicode) characters…

Answer (score 2):

You can try the [SendWait](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff731008.aspx) method from .NET:

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'System.Windows.Forms")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("x")
```

From [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1249976/sendkeys-method-in-powershell) answer by @wp78de.

If that fails, you may need to use some other methods:

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38524423/2118271) walks through changing your keyboard language temporarily to send text.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55248716/7411885) suggests using win32 `SendMessage` API methods instead of emulated key presses.

Comment: Unfortunately, `SendWait` sends  Keyboard Scan Codes rather than (unicode) characters… (the same as _ComObject_ `Wscript.Shell` (see [another comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66806701/powershell-sendkeys-doesnt-work-properly-with-arabic-character#comment118094434_66806701))

Comment: This worked perfectly in Arabic. Many thanks @Cpt.Whale.